# Android graphics - porting from existing AWT application

Tags: android, awt, android-canvas

I am porting an existing AWT application to Android. My application makes use of the following code:

```
Graphics g = getGraphics();
```

How do I translate that to get the current canvas?

Also, a lot of my code goes on to do the following:

```
FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
```

What existing classes within Android can I use? My current class extends SurfaceView if that helps.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For `FontMetrics`, you'll want to check out [Paint.fontMetrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html).

As for `getGraphics()`, I'm not exactly sure what it is. But briefly reading the method description, I believe it is similar to `getContext()` in Android.

I'm not as familiar with Android as many people around here, so if I'm mistaken, feel free to correct me.